# Click event for date-picker icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, bootstrap-datepicker

I want to open date-picker, when I click a calendar icon.

The calendar icon is inside of this template (in the i tag):

```
     var iconTemplate = '<li id=\"{streamID}\" class=\"list\">{streamName} <i class="fa fa-calendar pull-right"></i></li>';
```

Can I add an onclick event inside of this html template or do I need to make a function?

The code to trigger the datepicker is:

```
('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

The problem is, I can't just say:

```
iconTemplate.onclick=function(){ ('.datepicker').datepicker()};
```

because I only want the click event to be on the calendar icon, which is inside of iconTemplate.

****EDIT****

I tried the code below, but I'm thinking it didn't work because I don't actually reference the class 'fa-calandar' in the html--the only time it appears is in the js file, stored inside of the var iconTemplate. Do I need to reference a class from the html file in order to use the click function?

```
    $('.fa-calendar').click(function(){
      $(this).datepicker();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
('.datepicker').datepicker()
```

to this:

```
('.fa-calendar').datepicker()
```

You can add a click event like so:

```
$('.fa-calendar').click(function(){
  $(this).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I add in the click?